# How to get the value of specific field in JsonNode in JAVA

Tags: java, json

I have some JSON documents. Here is the JSON structure.

```
{
    "header":
    {
        "file1":0,
        "file2":1,
        "subfiles":{
          "subfile1":"true",
          "subfile2":"true",
        }
    },

    "response":
    {
        "number":678,
        "start":0,
        "docs":[
            {
                "id":"d3f3d",
                "code":"l876s",
                "country_name":"United States",
                "city":"LA"
            },
            {
                "id":"d2f2d",
                "code":"2343g",
                "country_name":"UK",
                "city":"London"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to get the value in "id" field using JsonNode. How to access to specific fields (id, city or country_name) in structure like this?  I try to use:

```
JsonNode node = documentHandle.get();
String s = node.path("id").asText();
```

But I didn't get anything expect null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your node points to the root of the JSON document. To get to `id`, you have to traverse the path.

```
ArrayNode docs = node.path("response").path("docs");
for (JsonNode doc: docs) { // this is pseudo-code
  String s = doc.path("id").asText();
}
```

Or use `JsonPath`.

Answer (score 0):

Jayway's JsonPath works well for this:

```
JsonPath.read(jsonString, "$.response.docs[*].id");
```